# Groups in TestNG, running groups from one class sequentially

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I have this class that involves tests revolving around a page object. However, I have 3 groups that aim to test different things in the same class. They all belong to their own group, and I am calling on them like this in the xml file.

```
<groups>
   <run>
      <include name = "hamburger_tests"/>
      <include name = "calc_pay"/>
   </run> 
 </groups>
 <classes>
   <class name = "com.autotrader.mdot.testsuites.smoke.hamburger_smoke.HamburgerButtonTests"/>
 </classes>
```

I was expecting them to run parallel, as in their own separate web driver, but instead the first group just failed quickly, and the second one flew by. I set the parallel attribute in  to "methods" which is what I hear you were supposed to do. How can i do this??

Comment: Testng does not have parallel by groups.  Parallel by methods will invoke each test in another thread, which would not work if you have a shared driver instance.

Comment: So your saying I can run tests that involve the same page object at the same time, but for ones that involve a different driver I can not do?